# We cannot ask questions about parallelism?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/481213/191178), in my opinion, seems to be concerned with parallelism. I would definitely consider parallelism as part of grammar. The comments are being needlessly specific.

First of all, I don't think anyone says "on first date". People usually say "on first dates" or "on the first date".

> During job interviews , ON FIRST DATES , and when meeting new coworkers

It is possible to say:

1. During job interviews, first dates, and personal introductions
2. During a job interview, a first date, and a personal introduction
3. When getting interviewed for a job, going on a first date, and meeting new coworkers

Comment: How are the comments being needlessly specific? Are you talking about comments that are now deleted?

Comment: @Laurel Actually just the first comment now. I think the comment is unhelpful. Instead of probing the OP for details, one may take account of context. Contextually, it appears to be about parallel writing. I would choose *on first dates* because it is more parallel than *on the first date*.

Comment: You make some good points that could be made at that question. But what is your question here for meta?

Answer (score 3):

Does this look like a question about parallelism to you?

> #### Which is correct , on first dates or on first date?
>
> Is correct to say "on first dates" ?
> Or the correct form is on first date ? Is it suppose to be "on first few dates?"

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/481213/1) is the version of the post that the first comment was asking about, as you can see from the timestamps (i.e. the first comment was posted 11 hours ago, the clarification was given 10 hours ago, and the question was edited 3 hours ago). As most of the comments indicated, adding the context here mattered. Now that the context was added, all of the comments can be deleted.

The question does have close votes, most of which (currently 2/3) are voting for migration to ELL. This seems like a fair decision to me considering the nature of the question and the proficiency of the asker.

Comment: The question may still be about parallelism.

Comment: @DoubleU Readers should not have to guess what a question is about. The author should include that information in the question.